# SSH Public key access - my password is being stored somewhere?

Tags: terminal, password, ssh, keychain

I've just created a Public/Private key to access my server via SSH, this has all worked fine but I added a passphrase to the key when it was created.

The first time I logged in via terminal and Cyberduck I was prompted for the passphrase but now I am not.

I chose for my password not to be stored and I can't see anything relating to it in my Keychain Access program.

It must be being stored somewhere, so how to I make sure I am prompted for the passphrase each time?

Comment: Mac OS X has `ssh-agent` enabled. Check out : http://serverfault.com/questions/627452/osx-ssh-agent-caching-passphrases-but-when-cleared

Comment: Actually I needed to follow a few links to https://discussions.apple.com/message/26795372